# Parse JSON string in Java without keys

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am new to parsing JSON in java. I have this JSON string:

```
[
{
    "projectId":5,
    "userName":"clinician",
    "projectName":"r",
    "projectSummary":"r",
    "projectLanguage":"r",
    "contactPersonName":"r",
    "contactPersonCV":"r",
    "contactPersonEmail":"r",
    "contactPersonPhone":"r"
},
[
    {
        "consentFileId":2,
        "projectId":5,
        "consentDescription":"r",
        "consentFileName":"test.pdf",
        "servicePathToGetConsentPdf":null
    },
    {
        "consentFileId":3,
        "projectId":5,
        "consentDescription":"rrr",
        "consentFileName":"test.pdf",
        "servicePathToGetConsentPdf":"localhost:8080/4c_viewFile?consentFileId=3"
    }
],
[
    {
        "anonymized_patient_identifier":"r",
        "projectId":5
    },
    {
        "anonymized_patient_identifier":"2",
        "projectId":5
    },
    {
        "anonymized_patient_identifier":"5",
        "projectId":5
    }
]
```

]

I have managed to get values from simpler JSON strings but this one has multiple levels and also there is no key in each level. I tried with simple code like this:

```
     Object obj = parser.parse(data);
     JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
     resultJson = (String) jsonObject.get("projectId");
     resultJson += "\n";
     resultJson += (String) jsonObject.get("userName");
```

but I get the error [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject] And also I don't understand how I will get the values in lower level without a key. I tried also to save it as a JSONArray but it didn't work.

Comment: The outermost element in your JSON is an array, and you're (inexplicably) trying to cast it to an object. Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: You should parse it to JSONArray, and then cast it to JSONObject with id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your root of `json` is type of `JSONArray`, 
the first object stored in the root array is an object, you can retrieve it by using `index = 0` .

this is a hack to make your code work:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(data);
 JSONObject jsonObject=obj.getJSONObject(0);
 resultJson = (String) jsonObject.get("projectId");
 resultJson += "\n";
 resultJson += (String) jsonObject.get("userName");
```

NOTE:

to convert a String to JSONArray, you can do :

```
JSONArray array = JSONArray.fromObject(data);
```

Comment: I have another error now. I use netbeans and the error is: cannot find symbol about method getJSONObject(int).  I have imported org.json.simple.JSONObject; and I searched it on goole but I only found articles about android.

Comment: @user1431148 have you imported this :  net.sf.json.JSONArray; ? if yes make sure you've downloaded the newest package

Comment: I still have the same error. Also I use simple.JSONObject and if I use net.sf.json.JSONArray I get java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONArray. So which libraries should I use?

Comment: you should only use ONE json library. if you haven't done too much with org.json.simple package, then i recommend you replace all your code and start using net.sf.json.JSONArray.

Comment: Does it have a parser? Because I can't find it or I have to do it differently than JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); Object obj = parser.parse(data);

Comment: @user1431148 i've added how to convert String to JSONArray in my question mate

Comment: @user1431148 sorry at first i didn't realize it.

Comment: Now I have a different error :[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException   in line  jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(data);  If I remove it there is no error.

Comment: @user1431148 I see, u don't have apache.commons package, well u need that package, but trust me mate, once u configured it properly u never look back :)

Comment: Well I have imported all these libraries but it still doesn't work. Anyway I will find a way I believe! Thanks for all your help ;)

Comment: @user1431148 if memory servers well, I think you need apache.commons.lang , apache.commons.io , net.sf.json packages, but i know your pain bud, the number of times I banged my head for not having proper packages...

Answer (score 1):

To improve on nafas answer, I would do this to see all the objects in the array:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(data);
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size (); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject=obj.getJSONObject(i);
    resultJson = (String) jsonObject.get("projectId");
    resultJson += "\n";
    resultJson += (String) jsonObject.get("userName");
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, the content of the array is heterogeneous and content are not all objects with that fields...